# How can I retrieve a document with a defined amount of sorted nested fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my problem: let's assume I have a Facebook post indexed on ElasticSearch. This post has many comments as nested fields, which, themselves, have a "likes" count. So, the mapping would be something like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "post": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "comments": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "like_count": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A post could have thousands of comments, but what if I want to retrieve only the 10 most liked comments from a certain post (so I'd have to define the post's id, limit a size for the field array and define a sort rule)? Is it possible? I've tried many ways using the "nested" query, but with no success.

Any ideas?

Edit: one of the queries I tried, in case anyone still has a doubt about what I want:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "id": 81500
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "comments.like_count":
                {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
        }
    ],
    "nested": {
        "path": "comments",
        "inner_hits": {
            "size": 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your query?

Comment: @kiran.koduru Added one of the queries I tried.

Comment: What do you get if you remove the `nested` field? I believe it needs to go inside the `query` field according to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

Comment: If I remove the nested field, I get all of the comments. I only want 10 of them

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "id": 81500
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "comments.like_count":
                {
                    "order": "desc"
                }
        }
    ],
    "size": 10
}
```

Comment: Not what I need. This query brings me 10 posts, not 10 comments.